# Resharper show potential fixes (ctrl + .) not working with stylecop

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2019, stylecop

I very often use `ctrl + .` resharper shortcut to fix errors in my code. It works perfectly with "standard" errors, but after installing `StyleCop.Analyzers` I can no longer open suggestions with a shortcut. IDE even suggest to use `ctrl + .`, but after pressing it either nothing happens or a window with other unconnected options pops up. In order to fix anything I need to hover with mouse and then correct context menu shows up. For example:

[image]

After pressing `ctrl + .` what I can see is:

[image]

How do I fix it so I can use `ctrl + .` shortcut with StyleCop errors?

I'm using VS2019 with ReSharper 2020.